# Tensorflow: Not able to train my model because of checkpoint file

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

I am trying to setup Tensorflow's [Object Detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/object_detection) and following [this doc](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/g3doc/running_locally.md)

I am getting the following error while I am training my model (It complains for the checkpoint file not found but it is there):

```
 python object_detection/train.py --logtostderr --pipeline_config_path=/c/ObjectDetection/models/model/faster_rcnn_resnet101_voc07_2.config --train_dir=/c/ObjectDetection/models/model/train
 INFO:tensorflow:Scale of 0 disables regularizer.
 INFO:tensorflow:Scale of 0 disables regularizer.
 INFO:tensorflow:Scale of 0 disables regularizer.
 INFO:tensorflow:Scale of 0 disables regularizer.
 INFO:tensorflow:Scale of 0 disables regularizer.
 INFO:tensorflow:Scale of 0 disables regularizer.
 INFO:tensorflow:Summary name Learning Rate is illegal; using Learning_Rate instead.
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "object_detection/train.py", line 198, in <module>
tf.app.run()
   File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 48, in run
_sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
   File "object_detection/train.py", line 194, in main
worker_job_name, is_chief, FLAGS.train_dir)
   File "C:\ObjectDetection\models\object_detection\trainer.py", line 218, in train
var_map, train_config.fine_tune_checkpoint))
   File "C:\ObjectDetection\models\object_detection\utils\variables_helper.py", line 122, in get_variables_available_in_checkpoint
ckpt_reader = tf.train.NewCheckpointReader(checkpoint_path)
   File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 118, in NewCheckpointReader
return CheckpointReader(compat.as_bytes(filepattern), status)
   File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\contextlib.py", line 66, in __exit__
next(self.gen)
   File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 466, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
 tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to get matching files on /c/ObjectDetection/faster_rcnn_resnet101_coco_11_06_2017/model.ckpt: Not found: FindFirstFile failed for: /c/ObjectDetection/faster_rcnn_resnet101_coco_11_06_2017 : The system cannot find the path specified.
```

---

**I have tried the checkpoint file path in both Windows and Linux format and I am getting the following error:**

**Windows format path** ('C:\ObjectDetectionaster_rcnn_resnet101_coco_11_06_2017\model.ckpt')

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: 
Failed to get matching files on C:\ObjectDetection
                          aster_rcnn_resnet101_coco_11_06_2017\model.ckpt: Invalid argument: 
FindFirstFile failed for: C:/ObjectDetection
           aster_rcnn_resnet101_coco_11_06_2017 : The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

**Linux format path** ('/c/ObjectDetection/faster_rcnn_resnet101_coco_11_06_2017/model.ckpt')

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: 
Failed to get matching files on /c/ObjectDetection/faster_rcnn_resnet101_coco_11_06_2017/model.ckpt: Not found: 
FindFirstFile failed for: /c/ObjectDetection/faster_rcnn_resnet101_coco_11_06_2017 : The system cannot find the path specified.
```

---

- OS: Windows 10
- Git bash command prompt
- Python 3.5.2
- tensorflow 1.3.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your error messages say, it's an issue with the paths, rather than an issue with a TensorFlow function.

Even in Git Bash, I use standard windows style paths, ie 'C:\' instead of '/c/'. Additionally, you need to escape your `\`'s or make it a raw string. Such as:

```
'C:\\ObjectDetection\\faster_rcnn_resnet101_coco_11_06_2017\\model.ckpt'
# or
r'C:\ObjectDetection\\faster_rcnn_resnet101_coco_11_06_2017\\model.ckpt'
```

Notice that in your pasted path, it says `C:\ObjectDetectionaster_rcnn_...` instead of `C:\ObjectDetection\faster_rcnn_...`. That's because `\f` refers to the escape sequence:

```
>>> print('\f')


>>> ord('\f')
12
>>> print('\\f')  # escape the slash
\f
>>> print(r'\f')  # or use raw strings with the 'r' prefix
\f
```